# Accessing a variable field within mongoDb $match aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, restheart

I'm trying to dynamically filter some data via an aggregation, passing the column and the date as a parameter into the aggregation.

```
{"$match":
    {"\"$$dateFilter.column\"": {"$gte": "ISODate(\"$$dateFilter.value\")"}}
}
```

And this is how I call the aggregation (via RestHeart HTTP call) :

```
https://<server>/<collection>/_aggrs/<aggregationUri>?np&avars={ "dateFilter": {"column": "startDateTime", "value": "2020-12-01T00:00:00.0Z"}}
```

It doesn't throw an error but doesn't return any information. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

in RESTHeart you need to use [json representation of json](https://restheart.org/docs/representation-format/#bson-types)

dates are represented as `{"$date": <epoch_time_millis>}`

try something like:

```
https://<server>/<collection>/_aggrs/<aggregationUri>?np&avars={"dateFilter": { "column": "startDateTime", "value": {"$date": 1605135600000 }}}
```

1605135600000 is the epoch time (in milliseconds) of 2020-12-01T00:00:00.0Z